# Cannot open terminal on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-terminal, chrome-extension

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and so far everything was great but yesterday it started to be weird.

Issues I found so far:

1. terminal won't open after reboot, but when I log out and then log in it works
2. sound is not working (tried few things but still no luck)
3. cannot open nautilus

What I did before it started to act weirdly was that I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop and added google account to online accounts.

I cannot figure out how to fix this and is it related to chrome remote desktop.

I will appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you install the Chrome Remote Desktop, all the windows are opened in a virtual desktop/workspace (which you can connect to remotely). The audio is also routed to the same desktop/workspace. After logging out of the current session and logging back in, you assume control over the current active session and everything seems to work.

If you want a quick solution to get your system working, just switch to a different virtual desktop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>) and enter

```
sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop
```

after logging in to your account on the virtual desktop.
To resume back on the gnome session, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>.

Alternatively, MDMower provided a great answer on configuring your Chrome Remote Desktop installation here:
https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/#answer-850359

Comment: I removed chrome remove desktop and now everything works. Thanks!

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu 18.04, this is a quicker summary of MDMower's post. https://medium.com/@vsimon/how-to-install-chrome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-52d99980d83e Also, I installed XTerm via the ubuntu software store as a temporary terminal. Everything works now.

Comment: Note this also fixes the same related "no sound" issue and the "YouTube videos won't play" issue on Ubuntu 18.04 for me too!